# GIT merge with main stream and edit my own version at the same time

Tags: git, github

I find an open source system which it has 80 % of functions i need. I want to clone it and add the remaining functions. As those functions are very specific and the open source only maintain by the owner, i will not commit my code to it. Can i do the following and how

1. i clone the existing version, then i keep editing the source code.
2. when there is update in that system, i get that update and merge to my source code
3. of course, all things do in GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although you might want to make things even simpler and start by *forking* the original (assuming that the original is also on GitHub already). That will form your own repo on GitHub directly, and now you can clone that to your computer and start playing.

The thing to realize is merely that the repo on your computer is allowed talk to more than one *remote* (the repos on GitHub). Thus there is no reason why you should not push commits to your repo on GitHub, and then turn to the original and ask to fetch anything new it may have to offer. Any push or fetch/pull is allowed to specify what remote it is supposed to talk to. After a fork, the original is usually named `upstream` while your fork on GitHub is usually termed `origin`, but those are just conventions.

The way this works is that in addition to the branch(es) you can see directly, you have "remote branches" that "track" (are configured to correspond to) branches by the same name up at GitHub on a certain remote repository. So for example if you have a branch `master`, you also have a "remote branch" called `origin/master` correspond to `master` on the repo at GitHub that you cloned from originally.

Well, different remotes have different remote branches on your machine, so your copy of git never gets confused about where stuff comes from and who it should talk to. Nothing will ever tromp on anything accidentally (especially if you confine yourself to saying `fetch` and don't say `pull`).

To illustrate, I'll start by cloning my own fork of someone else's GitHub repo:

```
humlet:Downloads matt$ git clone https://github.com/mattneub/Animate-body.git
Cloning into 'Animate-body'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 35, done.
remote: Total 35 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 35
Unpacking objects: 100% (35/35), done.
humlet:Downloads matt$ cd Animate-body/
```

Now I'll turn to the original repo that my repo was forked from, and turn it into a remote for the repo here on my computer (this should actually be all on one line):

```
humlet:Animate-body matt$ git remote add upstream 
    https://github.com/imyrvold/Animate-body.git
```

Now I'll do a fetch from the original:

```
humlet:Animate-body matt$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching upstream
From https://github.com/imyrvold/Animate-body
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
```

To see what the result is, I'll list all my branches:

```
humlet:Animate-body matt$ git branch --list --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/fix
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

So my workspace `master` is unaffected, but behind the scenes I've got a remote branch `origin/master` that tracks `master` on my GitHub repo, and another remote branch `upstream/master` that tracks `master` on the original GitHub repo that I forked from. I can fetch into *either* of those at any time and then merge into my workspace `master` as desired. I can also push from my `master` through `origin/master` to the `master` on my GitHub repo; but I can't do that with `upstream/master` because I have no write privileges on that repository (which is why I forked in the first place)!

Answer (score 0):

To 1.:
`git clone <repo-url>` (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)

To 2.:
Simply rename the original remote from `origin` to `oldOrigin` and pull from that when an update occurs in the original repository (using `git pull -u oldOrigin <targetBranch>`)

I do not understand your question 3. But... if you mean that you want to host your repository on github, then either fork as the others suggested or create your own repo. In any case you should end up with a single repository and two remote's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
1- first you fork the repository, which mean you will have your copy of that repo on your github.

2- clone your own repo(the one freshly forked) on your machine and start working.

3- Your repo would probably be "origin"(name of your remote repo), while there's will be "upstream". Whenever they have a change you can pull from their repo onto your local machine, then you push to your repo.

But beware there might be conflict from time to time as the commit history will not be the same.